# Kill Derby Network Server after ip change

Tags: java, derby

I have some problem shutdown the Derby Engine.

**Server Start;**

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar server start -h 10.90.232.20
```

I have started Derby Network Server wiht above cmd command. And I have stop the Network Server with below command.

**Server Stop;**

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown -h 10.90.232.20
```

But if i change my ip of current network adapter while server up, i don't kill the current listening network server. Because Network Server started on different ip before.

**Also i have tried;**

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown -h 0.0.0.0
java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown -h localhost
```

But did not help. I can't reach old started Network Server. Is there any way kill all derby network server instantly without ip parameter?

Comment: It looks like `-h` and `-p` are optional arguments, have you tried leaving out the `-h` argument, or specifying by port `-p` instead?

Comment: No help. if direct using `java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown` localhost tried to shutdown by default. and `Connection Refused`. `java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown -h` or `java -jar derbyrun.jar server shutdown -p` return missing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. Change your IP address back to its previous value, then perform the normal Network Server shutdown command
2. Leave your IP address alone, and use an operating system command, such as 'kill' (on Linux/Mac) or Task Manager 'Stop Process' (on Windows) to terminate the java process that is running the Derby Network Server.

Comment: Right. If i reverse my ip to old value, i can shutdown the Derby without any problem. I have already doing this for shutdown. Problem is if standart user change the ip of the system while Derby Network Server Up, i can't kill old Network Server programaticly.